# App Engine access anotherusers contacts

Tags: google-app-engine

In app engine I am using

```
username= users.get_current_user()
query = gdata.contacts.service.ContactsQuery()
query.max_results = 10000
feed=gd_client.GetContactsFeed(query.ToUri())
```

to access the contacts of the user who is logged in.

I want to access another users contacts who users my app. This other user has given authsub and I have saved the token.
What do I do to access the other user, changing the username is obviously not enough because I must have to point it to the correct token.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why don't you select the other user's token from the datastore, then use that to access the service?

Answer (score 0):

See http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.html#offline.  You have to get a contacts client authenticated using your stored token, and connect to the service that way.  This is less of a GAE and more of a Google Apps API question btw.